# Get line number in subscripts with #line

Tags: swift, swift2, debug-symbols

I want to get the line number where I have called the subscript for debugging purposes (like index out of range and so on):

```
/* 1*/   struct Collection {
/* 2*/      // this works flawlessly
/* 3*/      func getElement(index: Int, line: UInt = #line) -> Double {
/* 4*/          print(line) // 16
/* 5*/          return 0.0
/* 6*/      }
/* 7*/       
/* 8*/      // error: Default argument is only permitted for a non-curried function parameter
/* 9*/      subscript(index: Int, line: UInt = #line) -> Double {
/*10*/          print(line) // should print 17
/*11*/          return 0.0
/*12*/      }
/*13*/   }
/*14*/   
/*15*/   let c = Collection()
/*16*/   c.getElement(1)
/*17*/   c[1]
```

As you can see the subscript version does not work.

Is there a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html: *"Subscripts can use variable parameters and variadic parameters, but **cannot** use in-out parameters or **provide default parameter values.**"*

Comment: @AMomchilov: Even if it were inlined, the compiler would still insert the correct line number. That's not the issue.

Comment: @VatsalManot oh, you're right, that preprocessing will happen before compilation. Hmm what reason could there be for disallowing defaulted values?

Comment: @AMomchilov: I'm not sure ... pondering over it myself.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for pointing this out. If you know another way (perhaps some macros or linters) to get the line number please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that this isn't possible! I just tested this myself (with Swift 2.2), and I can confirm that this happens.

There seems to be no workaround for this. It may or may not be a bug. If you think this error is unintentional, I encourage you to file a bug at https://bugs.swift.org.

---

**Edit:** @MartinR correctly just pointed out some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html) in the comments section:

> Subscripts can take any number of input parameters, and these input
>   parameters can be of any type. Subscripts can also return any type.
>   Subscripts can use variable parameters and variadic parameters, but
>   cannot use in-out parameters or provide default parameter values.

This *is* intentional behavior.

Comment: i think it's because of whole-module-optimisation

Comment: @ale_stro: I highly doubt it. Just checked, whole-module-optimization was turned off in my debug build.